# How do I refresh an image in a div in erb?

Tags: html, image, erb

I took the codeship image that tells you the status of your build, and put it on my site in html.  So, right now it looks like img src="http://codeship..../> The problem is that it does not refresh. I need it to automatically call the link to the image and refresh every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to add a meta tag to refresh the page every 5 minutes (300 seconds):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Codeship Status Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”300" >
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <img src="http://codeship...."/> 
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```